# Jquery Ajax call and simple PHP json string echo server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

My PHP code on Xampp

```
<?php
$data = ((**Refer the JS fiddle Link below for JSON data**));
//header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $data;
?>
```

my client Javascript code

```
function clickbtn(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/json/index.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType:'json',
                    //data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success:function(dataF){
                    console.log('SuccessMsg:'+dataF);
                        alert(dataF.surveyId);
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert('Error: Unable to connect to the server');
                    }
                });
}
```

I am able to dump the JSON from the php server on my browser console. But i am unable to see the alert "SurveyID" value on alert box.

**Kindly take the JSON data available in JS fiddle link and paste it in your PHP script and test it.**

If you are testing on chrome Please add the **((Chrome installation path))--disable-web-security** to allow cross domain origin policy and then run the JSfiddle link at your end.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3k653/2/) for client JS and PHP JSON data

Comment: What do you see on Network tab of chrome dev tools or firebug?

Comment: the JSON string from the server

Comment: so the content type is `application/json` and http code is 200?

Comment: @techfoobar : try adding flag to your chrome --disable-web-security and run the above. It will work

Comment: @Nomi the above code is PHP script. since i am unable to post the entire JSON data. I have it in JSfiddle link. You can copy it fro there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes jQuery (or the browser?) respone with a string instead of an object.
You have to ckeck this an parse it to json maybe. I've encountered this problem too often, so i' checking this every time.

```
function clickbtn(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/json/index.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success:function(dataF){
                    console.log('SuccessMsg:'+dataF);
                        if(typeof dataF != 'object')
                        {
                            dataF = jQuery.parseJSON(dataF);
                        }
                        alert(dataF.surveyId);
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert('Error: Unable to connect to the server');
                    }
                });
}
```

I think that the dataType parameter is sometimes ignored :(

Comment: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }**

Comment: you have a trailling comma after "actionflage" and all attributes in "surveyActionDisplayList" are not wrapped with doublequotest... and these are only examples. there much more. a good tool to clean it up: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `dataType` option instead of `contentType` if you need the response to be JSON parsed automatically by jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/json/index.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType:'json', /* dataType instead of contentType */
                    ...
                    success:function(dataF){
                        console.log('SuccessMsg:'+dataF);
                        alert(dataF.surveyId);
                    },
                    ...
                });
```

Comment: @Nirus - What i've pointed out is a definite error in your code.

Comment: i need a working version . Please post the working answer . Dont point the error

Comment: Also, you cannot expect that AJAX call (to localhost) to work correctly from within jsfiddle. So trying it out completely is out of question.

Comment: i am able to dump the data in my console .. Chrome Browser. So this confirms that i am able to receive the data from the server

Comment: Well, for me chrome correctly reports **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/PepsiCo/index.php. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.** when you attempt the AJAX call.

Comment: @Nirus if you are receiving all the data on console then you have mistaken in surveyId typo, check it surveyID or anything.

Comment: One way to debug the JSON is assinging it to a string and doing JSON.parse to it.

Comment: i cross checked it. still no progress

Comment: @techfoobar : try adding flag to your chrome --disable-web-security to allow **access-Control-allow-origin**. And then run the JSfiddle Link. It will work...

Comment: @Nirus - Thanks for `--disable-web-security` - never knew that! :-)